# Woocommerce Products Not Appearing

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In woocommerce/wordpress under products it says I have 159 products but it is only displaying 2. Please see screenshot for reference, do you know what is going on here?[image]

Comment: have you tried disabling other plugins? also please check your theme's functions.php, there might be something that changed product queries...

Comment: Yep disabled all plugins and they appeared now just activate them 1 by 1